# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of $\lim_{x \to 3} x^2 = 9$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, quadratics, epsilon-delta

I've been learning about $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs and attempted to come up with my own proof that
$$
\lim_{x \to 3} x^2 = 9
$$
exists (I did use some help from some textbooks). **Is my proof valid and free of redundancies?** My proof:

**Scratch work:**
Written formally, this is:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } 0 < |x - 3| < \delta \implies |x^2 - 9| < \epsilon
$$
We start off by simplifying the conclusion of the implication:
$$
|x^2 - 9| = |x + 3|\cdot  |x - 3|
$$
Now we have $|x + 3| \cdot |x - 3| < \epsilon$. Because $|x - 3| < \delta$, we have $|x - 3| \cdot |x + 3|  < \delta |x + 3|$. In an attempt to find a suitable $\delta$, we let $\delta|x + 3| < \epsilon$. Solving for $\delta$, we get $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{|x + 3|}$. There is a problem though: $\delta$ is defined in terms of $\epsilon$ *and* the randomly chose point $x$. The definition of $\delta$ can only depend on $\epsilon$. To get around this problem, we will have to estimate the size of $|x + 3|$.

We start of by assuming that $\delta < 1$, which implies that $|x - 3| < 1$. Solving for $x + 3$, we get $5 < x + 3 < 7$. We now know that $|x + 3| < 7$ when $\delta < 1$.  Since $|x^2 - 9| < \delta|x + 3|$ and $|x + 3| < 7$ (if $\delta < 1$), we have $|x^2 - 9| < 7 \delta$. In an attempt to find a suitable $\delta$, we let $7 \delta < \epsilon$. Solving for $\delta$, we get $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{7}$ when $\delta < 1$. So we have now deduced two restrictions: $\delta < 1$ and $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{7}$. To satisfy both restrictions, we let $\delta < \min \left\{ 1, \frac{\epsilon}{7} \right\}$. When $\epsilon > 7$, then $\delta < 1$ and when $\epsilon < 7$, we have $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{7}$. We can now write up the proof.

**Proof:**
For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $0 < \delta < \min \left\{ 1, \frac{\epsilon}{7} \right\}$ such that $0 < |x - 3| < \delta \implies |x^2 - 9| < \epsilon$. There are two things that can happen: $\delta < 1$ and $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{7}$.

*Case 1 - $\delta < 1$:*
The implication's hypothesis is $0 < |x - 3| < \delta$. Multiply both sides by $|x + 3|$ to get $0 < |x^2 - 9| < |x + 3| \delta$. Because $\delta < 1$, we know (from our scratchwork) that $|x + 3| < 7$ and $\delta$ is also less that $\frac{\epsilon}{7}$. This means that $0 < |x^2 - 9| < |x + 3| \delta < 7 \delta < [7 \frac{\epsilon}{7} = \epsilon]$.

*Case 2 - $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{7}$:*
For $\delta$ to be less that $\frac{\epsilon}{7}$, we must have that $\frac{\epsilon}{7} < 1$ (as per the definition of $\min$). Because $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{7}$ and $\frac{\epsilon}{7} < 1$ we have $\delta < 1$. Look to *Case 1* for what follows after.

$\square{}$

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your first displayed equation: you wrote $$\lim_{\color{red}{c\to3}} x^2 = 9$$

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I was asking whether my proof was correct and not redundant [edit: I edited my question to make that clearer].

Comment: I think you have a very good handle on this!  In the "sketch work" when you wrote "Now we have |x+3|⋅|x−3|<ϵ. Because |x−3|<δ, we..." I was sure where you were coming from our going to as we didn't have anything yet, but it became clear as I read what you were doing (attempting to find nesc and/or restrictions on $\delta$).  In any event I *very* much like that *after* doing all the sketch work you presented a *formal* and correct proof frome the start.

Comment: Oh.... An improvement would be to combine and not consider cases.  Just note:  If $|x-3|<\delta < 1$ then $0 < |x+3| < 7$ so $|x^2-9|=|x-3|\cdot |x+3| < \delta\cdot 7 < \frac \epsilon 7\cdot 7 = \epsilon$.  That's all you have to say....  After all you *don't* have two cases where one *or* the other is true.  You have *one* case where *both* are true.

Comment: Actually as I read case 2 is a bit of a botch. $\delta < \frac \epsilon 7$ and $\delta < 1$ does not in any way imply that $\frac \epsilon 7 < 1$ and that *doesn't* follow from the definition of $\min$.  If you have $a < \min(c,d)$ we have $a < c$ and $a < d$ but knowing that both $a < c$ and $a < d$ does *not* give us any information about how $c$ and $d$ relate.  We *could* have $a < c < d$ *or* we could have $a < d < c$.  And (although it defeats our purposes) we *could* have $d < 1 < \frac {\epsilon} 7$.  ... but even so, our proof *would* work.

Comment: ... Just to be perverse.  If $\delta < 1 < \frac \epsilon 7$ then $|x^2-9|=|x-3||x+3| < \delta \cdot 7 < 1\cdot 7 =7$.  But as $ \frac{\epsilon}7 > 1$ we know $\epsilon > 7$ so $|x^2-9| < 7 < \epsilon$.....  But it is perverse to bother trying to consider cases where $\epsilon$ is *large*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations, your proof is valid! Here are a few minor improvements you could make:

- It is simpler to set $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{7}\right\}$ than to require that $\delta<\min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{7}\right\}$.
- If $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{7}\right\}$, then it is automatically true that $|x-3|<1$ *and* $|x-3|<\frac{\varepsilon}{7}$. Therefore, there is no need to split your proof into cases. You can write it up as follows:

> If $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{7}\right\}$, then $|x-3|<1$ and so $|x+3|<7$. Since $|x-3|<\frac{\varepsilon}{7}$,
> $$
> |x^2-9|=|x-3||x+3|<\frac{\varepsilon}{7} \cdot 7=\varepsilon
>  \, .$$

- The final tip is by far the most important. Please use `\varepsilon` instead of `\epsilon`: it will make the users at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) eternally grateful.

Exercise: can you generalise your proof to show that the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous, i.e. for every real number $a$, $\lim_{x \to a}x^2=a^2$? The basic idea is the same: start by requiring that $|x-a|<1$ and use this to come up with an upper bound for $|x+a|$. Note that while $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$, it can depend on $a$.

Comment: I have two questions: (1) Why can we let $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{7}\}$ (2) How does $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{7}\}$ imply that $|x - 3| < 1$ and $|x - 3| < \frac{\varepsilon}{7}$ both are true?

Comment: @obr: I'm sorry but I don't understand your first question. Is it possible if you elaborate please? We need to show that there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-3|<\delta$, then $|x^2-3^2|<\varepsilon$. One value of $\delta$ that works is $\min\left(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{7}\right)$, and we know that it works because of the proof. Of course, you can pick a $\delta$ that is even smaller than $\min\left(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{7}\right)$, but you don't need to.

Comment: @obr: Regarding your second question, let $x$ be the smaller number out of $1$ and $\frac{\varepsilon}{7}$, and $y$ be the larger of the two. Since $|x-3|<\min\left(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{7}\right)$, this means that $|x-3|<x$. And since $x\le y$, we get that $|x-3|<x\le y$. Hence, it is also true that $|x-3|<y$. Does that help?

Comment: @obr Why wouldn't you be able to let $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{7}\}$? It's a strictly positive number, and as Joe has shown, it works to prove the limit, which are the only two restrictions on what $\delta$ can be.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to consider several cases. Define $\delta=\min\left\{\frac\varepsilon7,1\right\}$. Then, if $|x-3|<\delta$, it follows from your computations that$$\left|x^2-9\right|=|x-3||x+3|<\frac\varepsilon7\times7=\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 3):

The scratch work looks good, but in the final proof there is no need to split into cases. You can just write

> Given $\epsilon>0,$ take $\delta$ such that $0<\delta<\min\{1,\frac\epsilon7\}.$ Then, when $|x-3|<\delta,$ one has
> $$
> |x^2-9| = |x+3||x-3| = |(x-3)+6| |x-3| < (\delta+6)\delta < (1+6)\frac\epsilon7=\epsilon.
> $$